# Changing text of a website using Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

so basically I want to change a W Text into B. My code below is working fine but there is a lag when you refresh the page where it shows the W text then replaces it with a B. My second problem is that every 20 refreshes or so, the B Text doesn't replace the original. Can someone plz help fix my code so it doesn't make these 2 mistakes Thanks.

```
window.onload = function () {
    /* Add your logic here */
    var my_div = document.getElementsByClassName('c')[3]
    my_div.firstChild.nodeValue = 'B'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `onload` handler will run once **all** resources on the page have finished downloading. On larger pages with images and external scripts and such, this could take a while, especially on bad connections.

Attach a `DOMContentLoaded` listener instead, which will run as soon as the DOM structure has been downloaded and parsed by the browser.

If the document may already be interactive by the time the userscript runs, then don't attach a listener, just run a function that changes the text immediately:

```
if (window.top === window) {
  const fn = () => {
    var my_div = document.getElementsByClassName('c')[3];
    my_div.firstChild.nodeValue='B'
  };
  if (document.readyState === 'interactive' || document.readyState === 'complete') {
    fn();
  } else {
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}
```

But the document in your link is huge, and even DOM parsing takes a long time, then the above may not be fast enough, in which case you could attach a MutationObserver to the document *at the beginning of pageload* (with `@run-at document-start` and instant script injection), and change the `document.getElementsByClassName('c')[3]` as soon as it exists in the document, like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name             New Userscript
// @include          /^https://fork-accessuh-uh-edu-e3e0cca90dc751a6.sitemod.io/logout.phpsitemod/
// @run-at           document-start
// ==/UserScript==

const cs = document.getElementsByClassName('c');
new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
  if (!cs[3]) {
    return;
  }
  cs[3].firstChild.nodeValue='B'
  observer.disconnect();
})
  .observe(document.documentElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

`document-start` isn't entirely reliable, though - it will sometimes take *some time* to execute such a script. If you happen to be in an environment where the script doesn't run immediately, enable experimental instant script injection too, via Tampermonkey settings (Config mode: Advanced, scroll to the very bottom, Inject Mode: Instant).

Comment: Im sorry but i copy and pasted your code exactly but it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean, "didn't work"? The callback should run. Does the `.c` element not exist on pageload? Need a [MCVE]

Comment: Firstly i like to apologize i am new to this forum and to coding. Now to answer your question when i reload the page the W doesn't change into a B  like it did on the original code. When i look  at chrome developer for errors it cant find any.

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] that illustrates the problem, or at least link to the page that you're running the script on? If there are no errors, that implies that the script *is* running and is finding the `.c` to change, and is changing it. (unless the site has monkeypatched `addEventListener` to make it inoperable, which is extremely unlikely.) But without a [MCVE] illustrating the problem, it's impossible to know what a solution might be

Comment: I added a picture to my original post,  <td class="c">W
</td>, the W i want to change the W to a B. Thanks for all your help by the way!!

Comment: Your problem still isn't reproducible - see the live snippet in the answer, it works as desired. (Also remember [not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to post images of code - to make a [MCVE], post the *code text* that reproduces the problem)

Comment: That's interesting. The site is riddled with errors (see console), and the userscript runs when the document is interactive, after `DOMContentLoaded` has fired, so the `addEventListener` doesn't do anything useful. See edit - you can either run the function immediately, if the document is already ready, or use `MutationObserver` to be even quicker.

Comment: Note that the subtree `MutationObserver` method is *pretty expensive*, but it's probably the best (only?) way to change a site *while it's loading* (rather than doing something before or after it's loaded, which is a lot easier)